# What does zero sockaddr_in mean in SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, reachability, system-configuration, sockaddr-in

tonymillion 's Reachability has

```
+(Reachability *)reachabilityForInternetConnection 
{   
    struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
    bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
    zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
    zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&zeroAddress];
}
```

and AFNetworkReachabilityManager has

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *_sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
        address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
        address.sin_family = AF_INET;

        _sharedManager = [self managerForAddress:&address];
   });
```

which mean both recommend that this is the right way to check for internet connection.

But I think that in ONLY care that we are connected to the Wifi router, it DOES NOT care that the Wifi router has internet access, right ?

Some one says in [How to check for network reachability on iOS in a non-blocking manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314946/1418457)

> The first one tests whether it can reach google.com, while the second
>   one simply checks whether there's any internet connection possible
>   (which it thinks there is, even though there's packet loss).

is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to know what is *zeroAddress* in the above code section. It is the host address for which address you want to check reachability. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress) link.